# RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout, onCreate solution doesn't work with me

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm a beginner in Android, and I am using RecyclerView for the first time.
I followed a tutorial to write this code, but it shows me this error when i try to open the fragment:
     RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

I searched for this problem but all the solutions say that I have to set the adapter onCreate method, I tried this but it doesn't work.

This is my Fragment Code:

```
public class FoodList extends Fragment {


  //Mandatory empty constructor for the fragment manager to instantiate the fragment (e.g. upon screen orientation changes).
    public FoodList () {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.FoodList , container, false);

        // Set the adapter
        if (view instanceof RecyclerView) {
            Context context = view.getContext();
            RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.FoodList_recyclerview);

           List<Foods> foodsList  = getArrayList();
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
            recyclerView.setAdapter(new FoodListListRecyclerViewAdapter(foodsList));

        }
        return view;
    }


//    @Override
//    public void onAttach(Context context) {
//        super.onAttach(context);
//        if (context instanceof OnListFragmentInteractionListener) {
//            mListener = (OnListFragmentInteractionListener) context;
//        } else {
//            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
//                    + " must implement OnListFragmentInteractionListener");
//        }
//    }

//    @Override
//    public void onDetach() {
//        super.onDetach();
//        mListener = null;
//    }


    //this method return a list of all foods
    public List<Foods> getArrayList() {
       List<Foods> list = new ArrayList<>();
       //add data
        return list ;
    }

}
```

Thank you

Comment: @Akash Pal - not null but empty

Comment: I tried to add elements to the array but the same error occurs, I think the problem with the adapter but I don't know what is the problem

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this log message because you are setting the LayoutManager on the RecyclerView before you are adding an Adapter. It's nothing bad, it simply indicates that there is no data at the time the LayoutManager was added, so no layout work needs to be done yet. Just reverse the order of these to lines:

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
recyclerView.setAdapter(new FoodListListRecyclerViewAdapter(foodsList));
```

Comment: Well of course nothing changes, you aren't provided any data to the adapter. My answer addresses the message "No adapter attached; skipping layout". You need to modify getArrayList() to return valid data.

Comment: I modified it to return valid data and still it gave me the same error

Comment: What error are you getting? I just checked the source code of RecyclerView and that log message is only printed where there is no adapter attached, before layout. Can you update your code so we can see exactly what you are doing?

Comment: I was getting no adapter attached.
however, @Ben.p solution worked

Thank you

Comment: `LayoutManager` doesnt need to be added after `Adapter`

Comment: @josh_gom3z Adding the LayoutManager before is the source of the log message.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is this line:

> ```
> if (view instanceof RecyclerView) {
> ```

I suspect that this is always false, so your code inside is never executed.

When you write

> ```
> View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.FoodList , container, false);
> ```

the `view` variable will be whatever the root tag in your `layout/FoodList.xml` is. Common things to find here are `LinearLayout`, `RelativeLayout`, and `ConstraintLayout`, none of which are `RecyclerView`.

I think you can just delete the `if` check. Later on, you write:

> ```
> RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.FoodList_recyclerview);
> ```

This will work just fine no matter what type your root `view` is. So, I recommend this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.FoodList , container, false);

    Context context = view.getContext();
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.FoodList_recyclerview);

    List<Foods> foodsList  = getArrayList();
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(new FoodListListRecyclerViewAdapter(foodsList));

    return view;
}
```